# Нужна ли запятые перед словами "чем" и "нужно"?

Tags: запятые

"Прежде(?)чем перейти исключительно на растительные напитки(?)нужно обсудить этот вопрос с врачом"

Нужно ли ставить запятые?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Прежде чем перейти исключительно на растительные напитки, нужно обсудить этот вопрос с врачом.*

ПРЕЖДЕ(,) ЧЕМ, союз

Придаточные предложения, присоединяемые союзом «прежде(,) чем», выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми. При этом союз может расчленяться (в этом случае запятая ставится между частями союза, перед словом «чем»), но чаще целиком входит в придаточную часть (и не разделяется запятой).

*Предупреждаю тебя: когда будешь ему представляться, – войди тихо; не начинай говорить, прежде чем тебя не спросят; спросят – отвечай, понижая голос насколько возможно…* Д. Григорович, Карьерист. *«Когда найдено было электричество, – быстро перебил Левин, – то было только открыто явление, и неизвестно было, откуда оно происходит и что оно производит, и века прошли прежде, чем подумали о приложении его»*. Л. Толстой, Анна Каренина. *Воротник поблагодарил и радостно согласился прежде, чем Олечка успела сообразить, в чём дело*. Н. Тэффи, Жизнь и воротник. *Нередко случается на войне, что командир, четыре атаки которого не принесли успеха, чувствует надобность подумать, прежде чем отдать команду на пятую*. В. Быков, Волчья стая.

О пунктуации в конструкциях с составными подчинительными союзами можно ознакомиться здесь: 
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach3